# Android Studio : How to set an external file(photo from the camera) to an imageview

Tags: java, android, xml

Having some trouble figuring out how to set the imageview to the picture I just captured with the camera. Would be a bonus if there was some way to display multiple captured pictures at once. Whenever I click the button, a previous image captured appears, then the camera opens, which isn't right. Id like the imageview to be blank, I click the button, take a picture, then that picture is displayed in the imageview. I believe that this line is out of place, but i'm unsure as to how/ where to move it. `mimageView.setImageURI(outputFileUri);`

```
public class cameraclass extends Activity {
    int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 0;
    public static int count = 0;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.camera);
        final ImageView mimageView;
        mimageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.image_from_camera);




        // Here, we are making a folder named picFolder to store
        // pics taken by the camera using this application.
        final String dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) + "/picFolder/";
        File newdir = new File(dir);
        newdir.mkdirs();

        Button capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.take_image_from_camera);
        capture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // Here, the counter will be incremented each time, and the
                // picture taken by camera will be stored as 1.jpg,2.jpg
                // and likewise.
                count++;
                String file = dir+count+".jpg";
                File newfile = new File(file);
                try {
                    newfile.createNewFile();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                }

                //Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(newfile);
                Uri outputFileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext() , "com.example.android.com220finalapp.provider", newfile);

                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);

                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
                mimageView.setImageURI(outputFileUri);

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == TAKE_PHOTO_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Log.d("CameraDemo", "Pic saved");

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I believe that this line is out of place, but i'm unsure as to how/ where to move it.

`startActivityForResult()` is asynchronous. Your photo will not have been taken by the time that method returns. You need to load the image into the `ImageView` in `onActivityResult()`, if you got a `RESULT_OK` response.

However, while `setImageURI()` may work, it has never been an especially good idea, as it will freeze your app for a while as it loads the photo. There are many [image loading libraries for Android](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46) that will handle loading your `ImageView` asynchronously.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I've never used a Library before, as this is a group project we are all working on together with github, will everyone else need to download whatever library I use? Or by implementing it in my code will it be automatic.

Comment: @FrankMascia: "will everyone else need to download whatever library I use? Or by implementing it in my code will it be automatic" -- both. It is almost guaranteed that you are already using libraries. Look in your module's `build.gradle` file (e.g., `app/build.gradle`) for the word `dependencies`. The `compile` statements inside there represent libraries that you are using. Adding a library usually just adds another `compile` statement.